# WPF layout: Show button below a scaled down image

Tags: wpf, layout

I am a bit stuck implementing a rather simple layout requirement. I want to show an image and below the image a button. The image should be shown as a whole - so it should be scaled down if necessary but it should not be scaled up.

Here is what I want:

[image: mockup]

Seems simple but I can't figure out if this is even possible in XAML. Obviously a `Stackpanel` isn't working, neither is a `DockPanel` and I can't see a solution with a `Grid` either.

Here is my try with a DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Button</Button>
    <Viewbox 
        Stretch="Uniform"
        MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=bigImage, Path=ActualWidth}" 
        MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=bigImage, Path=ActualHeight}">
        <Image x:Name="bigImage"/>
    </Viewbox>
</DockPanel>
```

Obviously the image viewbox will always fill the remaining space so the button will always be at the bottom of the whole container and not at the bottom of the image.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
  <Grid>  
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Button</Button>
        <Image x:Name="bigImage" StretchDirection="DownOnly" />
    </DockPanel>
  </Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the DownOnly property. But the problem still remains as the button will always be at the bottom of the whole dockpanel container and not below the image.

Comment: That's why I set the horizontal and vertical alignment to Center: this way the DockPanel takes the size of its content, and the button is just below the image. I tried it and it worked fine... did you use exactly the same code?

Comment: I think he means that the button is stretching horizontally. You can add HorizontalAlignment="Left" to the button.

Comment: You are right. thank you. in my case HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" and VerticalAlignment="Top" does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Image Source="photo.PNG" Stretch="Uniform" StretchDirection="DownOnly"/>
   <Button Content="Button" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Grid>
```

You can use a single grid only. With the StretchDirection set to DownOnly there is no need to specify a max size.

Comment: But with the Height of the Column set to * the button will still be at the very bottom of the container and not right below the image.

Comment: It depends on what is the Parent of the Grid. Right now the Grid has no settings, so if it was in another Grid or Border, it would stretch to fill the maximum area like you said. If the grid is centered, it would use the minimum space and keep the button and image together. Can you provide a bit more of xaml?

Comment: +1: thanks for the suggestion. yes the grid is inside another grid. I went with what Thomas has suggested but thanks for the input.